# Spring Solr Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, solr, solrj

I'm getting error when I try query generation from method name. I can however use others that are already there. `findAll()`...etc.. Any idea why?

Note that I use `HttpSolrClient.Builder` for `solrClient()` instead of the old way (previously depreciated)

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories
public class SolrConfig {
    private static final String SOLR_CORE = "solr.core";
    static final String SOLR_HOST = "solr.host";
    @Resource
    private Environment environment;
    @Bean
    public HttpSolrClient solrClient() throws Exception {
       return new HttpSolrClient.Builder(environment.getProperty(SOLR_HOST)).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrOperations solrTemplate() throws Exception {
       return new SolrTemplate(solrClient(),environment.getProperty(SOLR_CORE));
    }
}
```

**Entity**

```
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "Address")
public class AddressSolr {
    @Id
    @Field
    private String id;
    @Field
    private String Street;
}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface SolrAddressRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<AddressSolr, String> {

    List<AddressSolr> findByStreet(String name);
}
```

**application.properties**

```
solr.host=http://localhost:8085/solr
solr.core=Address
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class SolrService {
    public static SolrAddressRepository solrRepositoryX;

    @Resource
    private SolrAddressRepository solrAddressRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        solrRepositoryX = this.solrAddressRepository;
    }
}
```

**Solr schema.xml**

```
field name="id" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"
field name="Street" type="text_exact" indexed="true" stored="true"
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And I'm getting below error message

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrAddressRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SolrRepositoryFactory$SolrQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryMetadata;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/NamedQueries;)Lorg/springframework/data/repository/query/RepositoryQuery;
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.remsdaq.Runner.main(Runner.java:9) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrAddressRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SolrRepositoryFactory$SolrQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryMetadata;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/NamedQueries;)Lorg/springframework/data/repository/query/RepositoryQuery;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:512) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:615) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:308) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SolrRepositoryFactory$SolrQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryMetadata;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/NamedQueries;)Lorg/springframework/data/repository/query/RepositoryQuery;
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SolrRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SolrRepositoryFactoryBean.java:91) ~[spring-data-solr-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

If I do `List<AddressSolr> solrlist = SolrService.solrRepositoryX.findAll()` with `findByStreet(String name)` removed from `SolrAddressRepository` then it works. `findOne()` works too. Just can't create my own query.

method keywords:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/1.2.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Spring Data Solr that you're using is not compatible with the version of Spring Data Commons that you're using.

As you've tagged your question with `spring-boot`, I guess that Spring Boot's dependency management is involved. It will manage the version of both Spring Data Commons and Spring Data Solr for you. However, you've overridden the version of Spring Data Solr in your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Spring Data Solr 2.0.x uses Spring Data commons 1.12.x, but you're using 1.11.x.

You need to update your pom so that these versions are compatible. You haven't shared all of your pom so it's difficult to provide concrete advice.

Assuming that you're using Spring Boot, you could use Spring Boot 1.4.x and remove your version overrides. Spring Boot 1.4.x uses the Spring Data Hopper release. Spring Data Solr 2.0.x is part of the Hopper release train.

If you're not tried to Spring Data Solr 2.0.x, you could use Spring Boot 1.5.x or 2.0.0 and, again, remove your version overrides.